# How to get an image when having indices of pixels

Tags: image-processing, color, image, rendering

I am doing a perspective projection of a list of voxel V={v1,v2,v3,...,vn} using the perspective projection matrix 3*4 to get the indices of each pixel pi=(xi,yi).

pi=P*vi

Once I get the indices, I used `ReplacePixelValue[]` function to get an image but i get an inverted image.

```
ReplacePixelValue[Image[Table[0, {x, 1, 512}, {y, 1, 680}]], indices -> 1]
```

I think the problem is come from the coordinates system. So, may be I have to convert the indices to fit the right coordinate system of indices. an I think this function can do the work (note the image dimension is 680*512 in my case)

```
convert[{x_, y_}] := {x, 512 - y}
```

Is it  Right?

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/193

Comment: The pitfall post relevant to this question is [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/3066)

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Indeed, but since you didn't mention what your link was to, I didn't make the connection until you called my attention to it.

Comment: @belisariusisforth, I think it is not duplicated because in these link there is any use or explanation of ReplacePixelValue[]. I am surprising why the ReplacePixelValue[] function is done so that it processes the image as a graphic! So, we have to invert the coordinate system each time we have indices not coordinates!

Comment: @Developer2000 Check `ReplaceImageValue[ ]`